# sorting a soccer league list

Tags: python, list

UPDATE....: RESOLVED!!!!I am writing a code that would take the size of a league , team names and a game summary  the first two number will be allocated to the team names and the other half is the result of the game:
ex:  3 1 3 3 will be interpreted as third team in the list  VS first team and result is 3:3

here is the code:

```
diff=[]
teams=[]
summary=[]
teampoints=[]
leaguesize=int(input("number of teams"))
for i in range(leaguesize):
 teams.append(input("enter team names:\n "))
 teampoints+=[0]
 diff+=[0]
numberofgames=int(input("how many games:"))
for i in range(numberofgames):
 summary.append(list(map(int,input().strip().split(" "))))
for i in range(len(summary)):
 diff[summary[i][0] - 1] += summary[i][2] - summary[i][3]
 diff[summary[i][1] - 1] += summary[i][3] - summary[i][2]
 if summary[i][2] > summary[i][3]:
    teampoints[summary[i][0] - 1]+=3
 elif summary[i][2] < summary[i][3]:
    teampoints[summary[i][1] - 1]+=3
 else:
    teampoints[summary[i][0] - 1]+=1
    teampoints[summary[i][1] - 1]+=1

leaguedictornary=dict(zip(teams, zip(teampoints, diff)))
sorted_by_val = {k: b for k, b in sorted(leaguedictornary.items(), 
key=lambda element: element[1], reverse=True)}
print(sorted_by_val)
```

the editor is not letting my paste the output here but if you run the code you will get my point.

as you can see  team points and goal difference are sorted but I can't figure out how to sort the team names so it's aligned with their actual points...

Update: Figured it out finally -- see the updated code above, in case anybody interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict()` as a map to note points and goal difference for a given team. For e.g. the key would be the team string and the value can also be a dictionary with key being `teampoints` and `diff`. This way after calculating the teampoints and diff you can print the result like:

```
for key, value in result.items():
    print(key + ": teampoints: " + value.get("teampoints") + " | diff: " value.get("diff"))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Sure, the result could be you `dict()` and it will look like `{"team1": {"teampoints": 1, "diff": 2}, "team2":  {"teampoints": 1, "diff": 3}}` and so on. So, while you're calculating the teampoints and diff store them in a `dict()` and assign them to the `key` i.e. team1 team2.

Comment: in my original  code, how would you convert "res" to a dictionary?  I am getting below error with what you suggested.  TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Comment: Ok, could you please share a sample I/O example for the code that you shared. It would make it easier to share sample soln around that.